# Как создать .txt в памяти и работать с ним как с обычным файлом?

Tags: python

Есть массив строк, которые нужно отправить как файл .txt без сохранения на диск.

Так с обычным файлом:

```
with open('2.txt', 'wb') as f:     
    f.write(zip_buffer.getvalue()) 
    send('2.txt')
```

А каким образом сделать, если .txt не на диске, а в памяти?

Comment: Отправить куда? В корзину? ;)

Comment: "отправить файлом .txt без сохранения"... нужно создать (а значит - сохранить), чтоб было "в .txt"... добавьте подробности в вопрос... что, куда и чем отправить?

Comment: ну мне нужно отправить строки байтов на webhook дискорд, если отправить их сообщениями, то они просто не отправятся(из-за размера строк), поэтому нужно отправить их в тxт формате либо ещё как-то

Comment: @Артемий, можете привести в вопросе пример кода для отправки файла, сохраненного на диске? А мы вам покажем как это сделать без сохранения файла на диск...

Comment: `with open('2.txt', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(zip_buffer.getvalue())
send('2.txt')`

Comment: Использовать модуль `io`, например `io.StringIO`: пример https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/5a780831079c69cd2351a2249d6c8397c6f27a57/csv__examples/reader_csv__from_text.py#L25

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для того, чтобы работать с файлами, созданными в памяти, можно воспользоваться встроенным [модулем `io`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html).

Пример для *текстового* файла:

```
from io import StringIO

text = """some text ..."""
file = StringIO(text)
```

после этого вы можете работать с переменной `file` точно также как если бы вы открыли файл на диске:

```
with open(filename) as file:
    ...
```

Comment: Ага так можно даже с архивом работать.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor, конечно, только для архивов нужно работать с бинарными данными - `io.BytesIO`

Comment: Ну да, но по сути примерно тоже самое... Когда маленький архив — удобно, лучше чем эсктрактить, читать файл, потом папку сносить...

Comment: @Артемий, воспользуйтесь `io.BytesIO`

Comment: я после отправки txt, и при его читки вижу данную проблему у тоесть он обёртывает в ещё 1 слой байтов `b"b'PK\\x05\\x06\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00'\r\n"`